# Looking for a single French word that could not be recalled clearly

Tags: vocabulaire

I am looking forward a French word that possibly starts with 'bl' and spells quite similar to the English word 'blazer'. This word describes some kind of boredom or frustration after a short period of pleasure or ecstasy. I could not remember it clearly and this bothers us for long. Anybody has any clue for it?

Comment: [*blasé*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/blase?q=blas%C3%A9) ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: Laure, you could put as answer and Terrnce set it as the right one

Answer (score 2):

le verbe "blaser" qui donne "je suis blasé !" ou "Oh la blase !" (familier pas correct grammaticalement me semble-t-il)

un "blaz'" ou surnom de "blason"